# Excel formula to find the index of ANY number within a cell

Tags: excel

Is there an Excel formula to find the index of ANY number within a cell?  For example, the cell may contain something like “Tylenol 500mg” or “Tylenol PM 300mg” or “Advil 5.55mg”. I need to know where the text ends and the numbers begin.

I’m hoping to avoid writing a macro, but will if there aren’t any existing Excel formulas. As always...Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890"))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

To deal with ones that do not have numbers at all.

```
=IF(ISERRROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1)),0,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")))
```

[image]

Or you can use this regularly entered formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1)
```

To deal with ones without numbers:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1),0)
```

Comment: I was trying to do like, `=SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1)` but that wasn't working. Do you mind explaining a little how it works? I've been looking at it and thinking, but can't really get the idea behind the `A1&"1234567890"` part.

Comment: I am adding the `"1234567890"` to the existing string so as it iterates through the numbers it will always find a match. If that was not there and not all the numbers were in the string it would return an error.  Your Search would also work if wrapped in MIN and add the string to the end: `=MIN(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890"))` but I only use SEARCH when looking for alpha character, FIND is shorter to types and numbers are not case sensitive.  @BruceWayne

Comment: Now you only have to test it in a cell, where you do not have any numbers.

Comment: @ScottCraner - nice edit, I would have done it with an IF formula, comparing whether the result is bigger than the length. But yours is probably a bit shorter.